# InvalidOperationException after checking for null in Async ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I have a strange issue where code inside an `IF` statement is running despite the condition being `false`.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string q, string room)

        ...
        // Set up collection of tickets, etc.
        ...

        // Filter by Room
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(room))
        {
            itTickets = itTickets.Where(x => x.Room.ToLower().Contains(room.ToLower()));
        }

        // Filter by Summary/Description
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q))
        {
            itTickets = itTickets.Where(x => x.Summary.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower()));
        }

        ...
        return View(await itTitckets.ToListAsync());
        ...
    }
```

When I attempt to access the controller without any parameters at site/ItTickets/ I receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

This error is hit **inside** the second if statement.

Stepping through the code:

- I have verified that both `room` and `q` are `null`.
- The first `if` statement does not enter inside the braces.
- The second `if` statement **does** enter the braces, and attempts to access `q`, which is null, which throws an exception.

Both statements appear to be identical except for the fact that the parameters and fields are different.

Both `itTickets.Room` and `itTickets.Summary` are of type `NVARCHAR(50)`.

When I check the Immediate Window I can verify that the condition in the `IF` statement is false:

```
?!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q)
false
```

Yet the code inside executes anyway. What's going on?

**Update**: I've noticed that if I make the method non-async it works as normal. Weird!

**Update 2** More complete version of the code as requested:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string q, string room, string submitter,
                                          bool? closed,
                                          int? page)
    {
        var itTickets = _content.ItTickets.Include(i => i.ClosingUser).Include(i => i.Submitter);

        // Filter by Submitter
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(submitter))
        {
            itTickets =
                itTickets.Where(
                    x => x.Submitter.LogonName.ToLower().Contains(submitter.ToLower()));
        }

        // Filter by Room
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(room))
        {
            itTickets = itTickets.Where(x => x.Room.ToLower().Contains(room.ToLower()));
        }

        // Filter by Summary/Description
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q))
        {
            itTickets =
                itTickets.Where(x => x.Summary.ToLower().Contains(q) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(q));
        }

        // Include closed tickets?
        if (!(bool) closed)
        {
            itTickets = itTickets.Where(x => x.Closed == null);
        }

        var results = await itTickets.OrderBy(x => x.Submitted).ToListAsync();

        return View(results);
```

Comment: `Nullable object must have a value` is because you're using `.Value` from a `Nullable<T>`, not because a string is null. You need to check where you have `Nullable<T>` or `Something?` (the question mark). Check the stack trace.

Comment: Paste all the code - as in previous comment maybe you use Nullable instead of string.

Comment: what value is x.Summary ? i bet that is where your nullable is

Comment: It would appear that Lasse and Klaudius are correct - there was another nullable which appeared to be throwing an error after the code I posted, but the exception was being thrown on a different line. x.Summary is a required field, and always contains a value. I will update my post with a more-complete copy of the code.

Comment: Did you try capturing the result from 'where(...)' in second `if` block to a separate variable and use that to `orderby(..).ToListAsync()`?

Answer (score 0):

Lasse and Klaudiusz both helped me figure out the answer - the exception was being generated from a line different to the one displayed in the output and identified by Visual Studio.

```
if (!(bool) closed)
```

was the culprit, with `closed` being a nullable bool. I changed that line to

```
if (!closed.GetValueOrDefault())
```

and the exception is gone.

I wish I could mark comments as answers. Thanks for your help!